# Can I fix the power seat in my ML430 myself?

Tags: repair, mercedes-benz, seat

My 1999 ML430 is on its last legs, and one of the issues is that the power driver's seat is stuck in one position, all the way at the back and partially reclined (my husband can drive it now, but nobody else can). My husband and I both have some electronics experience, and I've done minor repairs on other vehicles before. Is this a problem we can repair ourselves? How would we go about doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your airbag warning light on?  Especially if it is, you should check under the seat to see if any cables are unplugged - it could be as simple as that.

There are also two 30amp fuses UNDER the fuse box in the engine compartment. If the seat just stopped working completely it could be one of those. You have to unbolt the fuse box cover and look down by the ebox fan and you'll see them.

Comment: If the fuses are popped, it happened for a reason.  The seat mechanism might need to be cleaned at a minimum or disassembled, cleaned and adjusted at the worst if it continues to pop fuses from time to time.